Unlocked Packages - Post-Install Infrastructure Design Patterns
Background
This question is seeking to gain a better understanding on how we should and can implement unlocked second-generation packages to build modular applications on Salesforce. The primary challenge we are facing is integrating the metadata of our packages with the configuration
data essential to their operation. Quite infamously, CPQ and Billing rely on configuration data for their functioning, but the same argument can apply to permission set assignment records. Considering how these package are to be configured through the use of records, how would one go about managing the lifecycle (insertion, versioning, source-tracking) of these configuration records upon installation and upgrades of said packages?
A simple example around permission set assignments
Let's say we created a package with a custom object, several permission sets to provide different levels of access to said object, and nothing more.
We could manually assign each permission set to the correct user or permission set group.
Then, if we decide to add a permission set to the package, we could install the new version, and repeat the process. If we decide to remove a permission set, we could first remove the permission set assignments and then install the new version.
If we try to automate this process, we would run into troubles pretty quickly.
For instance, there will be rules that define which permission set is to be assigned to which user/psgroup: permission set ForAEs should be assigned to the AccExec permission set group. But, AccExec belongs to a different package, and although the metadata do not depend on each other, the post-install scripts do! Therefore, the existence of these rules create a dependency between this package and the package that defines the variables within those rules.
This results in what I'd like to call Package Version-dependent post-installation script.
So in a mycompany_base package v1, I've defined and laid the groundwork for the different profiles and permission set groups of my company, among other things.
Then in Sensitive info management package v1, I define permission sets to be assigned to every respective permission set group.
This assignment should be automated, but then I could make a change in mycompany_base in v1.5 that necessitates an update, not to Sensitive info management, rather to its post-install behavior, specifically its permission set assignments. Does that make sense? Are others facing similar issues like theses?
We could try to de-couple by always deleting all configuration data (permission set assignments), and re-inserting the correct ones, but this doesn't seem to be an acceptable solution. We are using permission set assignments for the sake of example, whereas there are many scenarios in which you cannot simply delete data just to reinsert it again to maintain data integrity.
A more complex example with CPQ & Billing configuration data
Let's imagine we have a package called CPQ Billing Base, which depends on the corresponding CPQ & Billing packages, and it involves all our Revenue Recognition & GL Rules, Tax Treatments, etc, somehow within it as records.
At version 1.0 of the package, we only have subset of our products included within the package. Over time as we roll out CPQ to extend to the company's entire product line, we create package versions with the new products. Well in this case, how would one go about setting up an installation procedure where

the new product records can be tracked in version control?
the existing CPQ configuration records are not inserted again, causing duplication?
the new product records are inserted parented to the correct records of the previous version?

Possible solutions
package.json
This seems to be fairly undocumented, but we could bootstrap some script file to be run after the installation by our CI/CD tool. I can imagine that, included within the install script, we could check for the existence of a custom post-install key in the scripts attribute of package.json and to execute a bash script, which could theoretically insert a tree of records that are defined in other tracked json files within the project. However, this script would get fairly complex very quickly, recursively checking for existing records and linking their IDs to the tree of records which we are to import. So this method does not address the handling of existing records. Also, what if we wanted to rollback to an earlier package version? All-in-all, it feels to me a very wonky solution...
Apex
I can imagine building a simple LWC, separate from all the other packages, that allow you to run post-install Apex code through the use of defined interfaces for each package that involves configuration data. This process can also be automated, allowing the CI/CD tool to essentially delegate doing the above solution from package.json to an Apex class belonging to the package version that implements a special interface. This class could first check the database for existing records, and handle accordingly. But then again, it can get quite complicated very quickly. Say that from one package version to another, we decided to remove some configuration data and add some too. That means there would have to be classes that are aware which version is currently installed and to which version we want to upgrade/downgrade to.

With metadata, unlocked packages manage their lifecycle, meaning they add them, upgrade them, or remove them (in some cases) according to what is in your unlocked package. With data, there is really no support for this. I hope I am mistaken.
I'm hoping anyone could shed some light onto these issues. As you can probably tell, I would prefer to arrive at a solution without the use of Salesforce deployment tools such as Copado and Gearset. I am an avid supporter of developing with second-generation unlocked packages using scratch orgs and CI/CD tools (such as Gitlab CI) for automation, but unless these issues are resolved, we would have to reserve their usage to features we roll out that are independent of configuration data and involve minimum post-installation steps (so we could potentially automate them.)

Separate from my answer, I'll point out that CPQ is an example of the anti-pattern of configuration as data. That's not how Salesforce is supposed to work. Configuration should be metadata. CPQ is one Salesforce product that uses this anti-pattern. I advise everyone I talk with to consider the implication of bringing products that use the configuration as data anti-pattern before implementing them in your org. The architectural risk should include understanding the risks and limitations of the devops process.

It's a broad question, but one that I've been particularly fascinated by for many years now. The challenge you're facing is a common one I see when people want to apply Infrastructure-as-Code concepts to Salesforce.
In general, the challenge you're facing is that neither of the two Salesforce development models address the space between the full org and the isolation of a package.
So, the solution is a new model. First, a bit of history:
History: Salesforce.org's Product Delivery
At Salesforce.org, we created a new Salesforce development model, kind of by accident, that we came to refer to as the Product Delivery Model. It was our alternative, a middle ground between the Org Development Model and the Package Development Model.
We built the model for open source managed packages, initially Nonprofit Success Pack (NPSP) then eventually all ~50 managed packages my team managed the release of years later.
While the model was built for ISV-style development, it was really just built for handling the parts of the Package Development Model usually left to some bash shell scripts or manual checklists. We wanted to make it really easy for anyone to get our products fully configured in their org or in an org to extend our products.
The Product Delivery Model defines the product as a set of automation recipes developed in source control to deliver complete product experiences to new or existing orgs.
The Composable Delivery Model
After years of working with the Product Delivery Model and thinking of how to improve it, I recently started defining an evolution: The Composable Delivery Model.
Key differences are less focus on an ISV-style managed package product and a greater focus on portability and composability of the delivery automation itself.
The Composable Delivery Model defines the source of truth as a composable set of automated delivery steps and plans developed in source control and delivered to orgs through fully automated pipelines.
The key principles are:

Easy Org Creation for Everyone:
Delivery is Part of Definition of Done
Portable and Composable

Read more in my blog post: Introducing the Composable Delivery Model
In Practice
Much of the Composable Delivery Model can be implemented today with tools like CumulusCI which were built to handle cross-repo composable development at the tooling level. What we've been missing is a clearly defined model for using those capabilities.
D2X is an open source Docker image and set of reusable GitHub Actions workflows that implement a comprehensive CI/CD process using CumulusCI on GitHub.
Scratch orgs are a great test bed because they make it very inexpensive to start from scratch to re-run your automation.
Investing in that automation and building up the pipelines to test and use it throughout the lifecycle are the tricky parts. But, the right model at least helps define the "product" as what it really means to the company/organization: something usable in an org, not a package version by itself.
